# How to only allow access to API from certain ip address

Tags: node.js, heroku

I currently have a node js server deployed to heroku. I want to restrict non-authorized domains from interacting with the API's. I know I can do this on the server side by either requiring authentication or by requiring specific request host. But is there a way to configure that on heroku? To only allow a specific server owned by me to call the node serer.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku most likey adds an `x-forwarded-for` header to requests it is sending to your application. You'll want to get the first address in that list:

```
const ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0];
```

Where `req` is a request object. This [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/get-my-ip-address?path=server.js) demonstrates it in action.

Using this address, you can respond to traffic depending on its IP from your node server.